# Fundmental class of a homology manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, orientation

Suppose $X$ is a compact, connected $n$-dimensional homology ($\Bbb Z$-)manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_manifold). Since orientability is defined using only homology (for example, in Hatcher's book), we can define orientability of homology manifolds. Suppose $X$ is orientable. Then is it true that there is a fundamental class of $X$?

Orientable closed, connected manifolds have fundamental classes (Theorem 3.26 in Hatcher [https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)), but the proof uses the local Euclidean condition of manifolds, so the proof doesn't apply directly to homology manifolds.

Comment: As far as I remember from my course on Algebraic Topology, an orientation is a choice of generators $\sigma_x\in H_n(X,X\setminus\{x\})$ such that, for every path $\gamma:x\rightarrow y$, $\gamma_\ast \sigma_x = \sigma_y$. More abstractly, $R$-orientations correspond to natural isomorphisms between the local coefficient systems $R$ and $H_n(X,X\setminus\{x\})$. I think Hatcher uses the existence of charts to prove that orientable smooth manifolds are indeed orientable in this more abstract setting.

Comment: I know this is true with coefficients in a PID.

Comment: I think there should be a proof using the Thom isomorphism; ideally there would be a stable spherical fibration coming from fiberwise suspending the map $E \rightarrow X$ where the fiber over $x$ is $X \cup \operatorname{cone}(X -x)$. This should play the role of the tangent bundle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is there a reference for a proof for it? I think PID coefficient would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References for Poincare Duality for orientable $L$-homology manifolds, where $L$ is a PID are:

A. Borel, "The Poincaré duality in generalized manifolds" Michigan Math. J., 4 (1957) pp. 227–239.

A. Borel, "Homology and duality in generalized manifolds" A. Borel (ed.), Seminar on transformation groups, Princeton Univ. Press (1960) pp. 23–33.

Another reference is Bredon's book "Sheaf theory" but I find it unreadable.

From these, you get the fundamental class and much more, of course.